# I want to filter a dataframe that contains all the days of year 2021 and 2022 such that I only have the data that belongs to 2021?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eYTw.png)
I only want to print only the data for 2021

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df[df['time'].dt.year == 2021]
```